# MySQL auto fill column according to another column

Tags: mysql

There is a column name called marks in mysql Table. marks are like 43,67,97,30,50 etc.

I want to create a another column which name is **position**. Data should be added to that column automatically **according to marks**.

Ex :

for marks 97, position shoud be 1,

for marks 67, position should be 2,

for marks 50, position should be 3,

How to auto fill position column like that?

Comment: You should actually be using a view to calculate and display `position`.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said

Comment: instead of adding a column to the same table, you better define a `view` to calculate `position` value dynamically. So on every update of an existing value or insertion of a new value, `position` is calculated auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `student` is you table with marks and position columns, try this query:

```
UPDATE student 
JOIN (
  SELECT id, IF(@prev <> marks, @s:=@s+1, @s:=@s) AS position, @prev:=marks AS marks
  FROM student, (SELECT @s:= 0, @prev:=0) s
  ORDER BY marks DESC
  ) t
ON student.id = t.id
SET student.position = t.position
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e63e/1

Answer (score 0):

Might need tweaking for when there are equal marks. Of course you will have to put this into a trigger if you want the position to be automatically updated. Alternatively, run the update immediately after modifying the data in the marks table:

```
create table marks
(
id int unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
mark int not null default 0,
position int not null default 0
);

insert into marks (mark) values (97);
insert into marks (mark) values (67);
insert into marks (mark) values (50);

update marks m
inner join (
select m.id,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
from marks m
join (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
order by mark desc
) t on m.id = t.id
set m.position = t.rank
;

select *
from marks;
```